# Images are displayed below the sidebar in the middle of the page and not from the top (Vue.Js)

Tags: html, css, vue.js, containers, vue-component

I'm building a photo website with Vue.JS and encountering the problem mentioned in the titled. I've tried everything, and after two hours of back and forth with ChatGPT I've decided to come here.

This is the code from the parent component ("MainNav")

```
<template>
  <div class="main_container">
    <header class="header mx-5 my-9 absolute text-xl">Gonçalo Dias</header>
    <div class="m-5 mt-80 space-y-1">
      <div
        class="sidebar-item"
        @mouseover="showInnerSidebar"
        @mouseleave="hideInnerSidebar"
      >
        Projects
        <div
          v-if="showProjectsInner"
          class="inner-sidebar space-y-0.5 mt-1 mb-2"
        >
          <div
            v-for="(project, index) in projects"
            :key="index"
            class="inner-sidebar-item indent-4"
            @click="handleProjectClick(project)"
          >
            {{ project.name }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>Diary</div>
      <div>Info</div>
    </div>

    <ProjectOne
      v-if="selectedProject && selectedProject.name === 'Project 1'"
      :style="{ marginTop: selectedProject ? '10px' : '0' }"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ProjectOne from "./ProjectOne.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    ProjectOne,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showProjectsInner: false,
      selectedProject: null,
      projects: [{ name: "Project 1" }, { name: "Project 2" }],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showInnerSidebar() {
      this.showProjectsInner = true;
    },
    hideInnerSidebar() {
      this.showProjectsInner = false;
    },
    handleProjectClick(project) {
      this.selectedProject = project;
      this.showProjectsInner = false;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.header {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

This is the code from the child component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="main_box project-image">
      <img :src="require('@/assets/Project1/001.jpg')" />
      <img :src="require('@/assets/Project1/005.jpg')" />
      <img :src="require('@/assets/Project1/022.jpg')" />
      <img :src="require('@/assets/Project1/034.jpg')" />
      <img :src="require('@/assets/Project1/036.jpg')" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup></script>

<style lang="scss">
.main_box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.project-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: 4px;
}
</style>
```

And this is how it's looking:
[pay no mind to massive size of the image, I'm trying to first resolve this issue before anything else](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rB66p.jpg)

I'm a beginner so there's not many solutions coming to mind, but with the help of Chat GPT i've fumbled with CSS properties, tried multiple variations, but nothing allowed my images to break that sidebar container. My guess is this is a problem specific of CSS and template relationship between components, so an issue that has to do with the Vue system.

Comment: The title doesn't make any sense. Images should be displayed "_from the(Vue.Js)_" What does that mean???  The code only does what you tell it to so we understand the actual behavior, it's your expected behavior that is confusing.  Please elaborate on what the page is supposed to look like.  Also, for a possible CSS problem, include in your question information about everything that can effect your styling.  Classnames like `mx-5 my-9 absolute` come from some specific library, probably? Let us know.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't noticed there was a word missing in the title. I've made the changes. Basically what I'm looking for is a scroll down display from the bottom of the page to the bottom, while the sidebar stays fixed. The problem is that the first image is being displayed below the sidebar and I can't make it go up in the page. 
The classnames you are referring come from Tailwind CSS, but in this case I'm pretty sure it's not causing the problem, as I've used Tailwind only for simple properties such as margins and font sizes.

Comment: I suspect that the sidebar div don't have any CSS set to make it a sidebar, so it just appears at the default location. Usage of LLM do make me ponder about if the CSS library implied actually exists though

Comment: @mcendu There's no specific CSS to make it a sidebar but it's not on a default location. The div below the header is taking care of placing it in the middle of the page. Also, the library does exist and was imported with no errors to my Vue project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did a mistake in this code by using adding `mt-80`. Remove it and see what happen

```html
<template>
  <div class="main_container">
    <header class="header mx-5 my-9 absolute text-xl">Gonçalo Dias</header>
    <div class="m-5 mt-80 space-y-1"> <!--in this line--!>
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
 </template>
```

If it's not working comment below.

```
Happy-Coding
```

Comment: it didn't work. Here's an image with the changes: https://imgur.com/a/b3LJbcQ
With the change I'm not even able to select Project 1 because although it toggles an inner sidebar when I hover over "Projects", that inner sidebar disappears when I try to click any of the items.

Comment: That didn't solve the issue but pointed out the problem and I managed to solve it. The problem was the place where I was importing the child component. I was doing it in a div that is inside the one with that class you mentioned. By changing my html structure and having the child component imported right below the header I managed to solve it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like the child component needed some fresh air outside the nested div!   Seriously though, glad you got it working!  Happy coding ❤️